# React-native firestore data modelling not working

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of groups created with firestore. Now I want users to become "Members" of those groups just by clicking on a "Join Group" button located in a particular group's screen. I've created a member model in firestore where I wrote the below code but it does'nt work

Comment: What I have tried:

//Adding a member model

export function addMember (addComplete, member) {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let member_id = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    const {currentUser} = firebase.auth()

    firebase.firestore()
    .collection('members')
    .add({
    member: member_id,
    email: currentUser.email,
    createdAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
}).then((snapshot) => snapshot.get()
).then((memberData) => addComplete(memberData.data()))
.catch((error) =>console.log(error));
}

Comment: Please edit your question, there's the link right under it, to show that code and mark it up.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the description of issue you are facing?